# Flask forms to pass arguments to python script

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

I am using flask but i wanted to create a form that can pass variables to another python script that will run when a user clicks submit. Can anyone point me to any examples of this? I have been searching for some kind of example of this.

Comment: You can use `os.system("python blah.py")` to run another program in your flask program

Comment: How would this work with passing arguments from a form?

Comment: When the arguments come, you can use a request to get the arguments, and then in that function, you can run another program